# Distinguished Badge

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges

Hit the rep cap on all 4 sites in one day.

Comment: For the community-oriented programmers who operate datacenters and must know each other's browser preferences!

Comment: Or, those addicted to reputation.

Comment: Which site would get the badge, all 4? Just meta?

Comment: Other possible names: "Drain of Company Resources", "Unemployed", "jQuery Must Have GreaseMonkey Whatever-the-hell-meme-SF-has".

Answer (score 1):

I'd think it'd be tough to hit the limit on Meta.

Comment: Ha, it is actually prety easy.  It seems people are a little more liberal with upvotes here.  I know I am at least.

Comment: @jjnguy: +1 because I'm even more liberal than you are.

Comment: I agree that people upvote here more often.  Partialy cause this site has nothing to do with your programming, server, or general knowledge.  It is just about the site itself, features, design, and good suggestions. Upvotes dont mean as much here.

Comment: I've hit rep limit on this site every day except 3 days since it's been open (and those days were weekend where there was nearly no activity)

Comment: @Pesto: +1 because I'm even more liberal than you are.

Comment: @Andy: +1 because I'm a damned pinko commie